# How can I get filled on the ordered qty via Binance API?

Tags: python, api, binance, cryptocurrency

I started to play around a bit with the Binance API and was wondering if there is a way to get filled on the actual qty ordered instead of the quantity after commissions (i.e. commissions are added to the price and not subtracted from the qty)? When executing below:

```
order1 = client.create_order(symbol = 'XRPEUR', side = 'BUY', type = 'MARKET', quantity = 11)
```

I get 10.989 XRP added to my portfolio but looking to get 11.

```
{....'qty': '11.00000000', 'commission': '0.01100000', 'commissionAsset': 'XRP',....}
```

Many thanks,

David